# MySQL syntax: What is this?

Tags: mysql, sql

My exported SQL file contains the lines below:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

What do these lines mean, unlike `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

They are [variable assignments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-variable.html). The assignments are [wrapped in executable comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html) in such a way that they are executed when MySQL is used and left alone if some other RDBMS is used. Furthermore, the 40101 indicates that the comments are not to be retained in the database i.e. if the lines are executed, they are only executed when the sql file is executed.

Comment: I will use this sql as a php statement for mysql_query. Should I ignore that lines or execute?

Comment: The first three store the old values and the `SET NAMES` is a shorthand notation for setting the value for `character_set_client`, `character_set_results` and `collation_connection`. Ignoring `SET NAMES` may cause your application to not work properly as expectations on character set is changed. Storing the old values is unnecessary if the values are not used later on to reset default value.  The scope of `SET NAMES` is global and the value is applicable throughout a single mysql session. You'd benefit from reading the documentation as it is quite good.

Answer (score 6):

Those special comment always confuse me, after checking the doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html

> if you add a version number after the ! character, the syntax within the comment is executed only if the MySQL version is greater than or equal to the specified version number. The KEY_BLOCK_SIZE keyword in the following comment is executed only by servers from MySQL 5.1.10 or higher:
>
> CREATE TABLE t1(a INT, KEY (a)) /*!50110 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1024 */;

That is not hard to understand. In term of 50110, means 5(major)01(minor)10(revision) = run that in MySQL version >= 5.1.10 or higher

Answer (score 4):

This is variable assignments wrapped within conditional comments. The code is executed depending on the version of MySQL in question, see [comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html)

Answer (score -4):

These lines are comment.
SQL Comment can start by `--` till end of line or can be surrounded by `/* ... */`

I think that lines are related to the file encoding of your exported sql file.

Comment: as other answer correctly states, these aren't simple comments